# Php & Mysql // FATAL ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

My server gave me back error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'MySQL server has gone away query: INSERT INTO vans (`name`, `make`, `model`, `age`, `body_style`, `cond`, `milage`, `booth_space`, `seat`, `doors`, `eng_size`, `pow_kw`, `pow_hp`, `fuel_type`, `transsmission`, `vrt`, `price`, `description`, `seller`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
```

Soo,how can I solve this problem? I tried to put manualy the sql,no any error.

The php code:

```
        $table=$this->vehicletype.'s';
        $data=array(
            'name'=>$this->vehicle['name'],
            'make'=>$this->vehicle['make'],
            'model'=>$this->vehicle['model'],
            'age'=>$this->vehicle['age'],
            'body_style'=>$this->vehicle['body_type'],
            'cond'=>$this->vehicle['condition'],
            'milage'=>$this->vehicle['milage'],
            'booth_space'=>$this->vehicle['booth_space'],
            'seat'=>$this->vehicle['seat'],
            'doors'=>$this->vehicle['doors'],
            'eng_size'=>$this->vehicle['engine_pow'],
            'pow_kw'=>$this->vehicle['kw_pow'], 
            'pow_hp'=>$this->vehicle['hp_pow'],
            'fuel_type'=>$this->vehicle['fuel_type'],
            'transsmission'=>$this->vehicle['transsmission'],
            'vrt'=>$this->vehicle['licence_date'],
            'price'=>$this->vehicle['price'],
            'description'=>$this->vehicle['desc'],
            'seller'=>$this->user['main']['user_type']

        );
        $id=$db->insert($table,$data);
```

The mysql database:
[mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0F5p.png)
I use own code. I spend 8hours in google to find the problem,but nothing,every question is connecting to some libary,but its my.

Comment: What library is that?

Comment: You not showing the full code

Comment: The code excerpt does not tell us anything. If you do a google search on the error message, then you can find the usual root causes. Try to tie your error to one of them.

Comment: Are you sure your SQL database is up? Can you log with command line?

Comment: Everywhere is working properly,just only here no.